# Hide URL parameters in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

How to Hide query String URL in Spring MVC

We are using third party URL, when we hit the URL it open a PDF, we want to hide some parameters in query string URL. In the URL there pass invoice number and Date both parameter we want to hide, when we hit URL in any ways.

If we cannot hide the using query string while using URL tag? What is the alternative for the above scenario.

URL: http://abcxyz/GetDocument?DocumentClass=INV&invno=098765546&invdt=11/01/2016

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a POST request rather than a GET, that way the parameters do not appear in the url, but this will depend on whether the third party will support a POST request.

A GET request will always show the params in the url. If you leave out the parameters, the request probably can't be completed properly.

A user would still be able to see what was sent even if using a POST request or javascript to fetch the document. Their browser's development tools will show the requests and the parameters. This makes sense since it's their browser that is making the request and you can't stop them from checking what data they are sending out or receiving.

One way I can think of is to have your server request the page from the third party and serve that to the user's browser. That way your user will be requesting the data from your server and doesn't need to know about the third party at all, you will have control over the url that serves the pdf.

One **caveat** I would add is that you might want to check the third party's terms of service to see if this would violate them.